# How to create an index view?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a view which is doing summation of several columns:

```
Select cola, colb, cola + colb + colc from table tbl_a
```

Can I know what are the indexes I should create for the view to improve its performances?

Comment: What is the actual performance problem that you have? How do the searches usually look?

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts...

- what filters or joins will you use on the view? These determine what indexes you'll need on the *table*
- have you considered a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191250%28SQL.105%29.aspx) to pre-sum cola+colb at the table level?

Personally, I avoid views because a view doesn't have persistence (unless it is indexed itself): it is simply a macro expanded by the query optimiser. That is, say you have 2 views that join (one with 3 table, one with 4 tables): the actual query plan will show all 7 tables.

In the case above, you have no filters. This means that no index can help you: you'll get a clustered index (which is actually the table and you do have a clustered index, right?) scan

Comment: Well, depending on the width of the table, an index on cola, colb, colc might be a lot narrower than the clustered index and therefore might provide a slightly more efficient plan. But otherwise I agree. Too many people think an indexed view is a magic way to make a view perform better, when the problem isn't necessarily the view at all...